# ElasticSearch show data according to restaurant_id and its average time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

> I am very new to ElasticSearch and I wonder if it is possible to show the data according to restaurant_id and then the average time to confirm the order. for example, I have documents:

```
{ _index: "orders-development",
_type: "order",
_id: "4412917",
_score: 1,
_source: {confirm_duration: 5}
}

{ _index: "orders-development",
_type: "order",
_id: "4412917",
_score: 1,
_source: {confirm_duration: 4}
}

{ _index: "orders-development",
_type: "order",
_id: "4322923",
_score: 1,
_source: { confirm_duration: 12}
}
```

The above are the documents stored in ES and now I have to show data according to restaurant_id and then the average of time. So now I am using below code and its showing error **"reason":"[terms] unknown field [avg], parser not found"**

```
aggregations = {
  avg_order_confirmation: {
    terms: {
      field: :restaurant_id,
      size: 100,
      avg: { field: :confirm_duration },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to move `avg` to a sub-aggregation of the `terms` one:

```
aggregations = {
  avg_order_confirmation: {
    terms: {
      field: :restaurant_id,
      size: 100
    },
    aggs: {
      avg_confirmation: {
        avg: { field: :confirm_duration }
      }
    }
  }
}
```